# starting a new thread in existing thread's uncaughtexception handler

Tags: java, multithreading, uncaughtexceptionhandler

If  an uncaught exception is thrown and you want to recover by restarting an identical thread to the one the exception was just thrown in (e.g JMS connection lost), what's the easiest way?

The class extends from Thread, and the thread has an UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: Can you show some code?  And I assume you are not able to catch `Exception` in your run method to handle this appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to "restart" the current thread via the run() method

```
void run() {
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done) {
        try {
           ...
           done = true;
        } catch (ConnectionLostException ex) { 
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```